# Silex - How to pass Request $request to $app->error(function (\Exception $e, $code) use ($app) {

Tags: error-handling, request, silex

I am new to Silex. I am trying to pass `Request $request` to `$app->error(...){...}`. Normally it would look like so:

```
$app->error(function(\Exception $e, $code) use ($app) { ...
```

I want to use Request within the error controller. The code below will generate en error. Any idea how to snick the `Request $request` object into this controller ? so I will have access to **request->getPathInfo()** ?

```
//...

$app->error(function(\Exception $e, $code, Request $request) use ($app) {
    if (404 === $code) {
        $path = $request->getPathInfo();
        $path = explode('/',$path);

        if($path[1] == 'php'){
            return $app->redirect($app['url_generator']->generate('php'));
        }

        if($path[1] == 'css'){
            return $app->redirect($app['url_generator']->generate('css'));
        }

        //...

        return $app->redirect($app['url_generator']->generate('home'));
    }
    // Do something else (handle error 500 etc.)
});


// RUN
$app->run();
```

Answer (score 4):

**$path = $app['request']->getPathInfo();**

```
   $app->error(function(\Exception $e, $code) use ($app) {
        if (404 === $code) {
            $path = $app['request']->getPathInfo();
            $path = explode('/',$path);
            echo $path[1];
            if($path[1] == 'php'){
                return $app->redirect($app['url_generator']->generate('php'));
            }

            if($path[1] == 'css'){
                return $app->redirect($app['url_generator']->generate('css'));
            }

            //...

            return $app->redirect($app['url_generator']->generate('home'));
        }
        // Do something else (handle error 500 etc.)
    });


    // RUN
    $app->run();
```

**Now I can redirect users when 404 based on the area they are in - to different predefined paths.**

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->error(
  function (\Exception $e, Request $request, $code) {
    //yours code here
  }
);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.  **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593)

Answer (score -1):

Try this code,

```
Request::createFromGlobals()
```